# scatterplot() formatting in car package

Tags: r

I want to differs the component of the scatterplot.

- the points
- the regression line (in green)
- the smoothed conditional spread (in red dashed line)
- the non-parametric regression smooth (solid line, red)

The output should be like this
[image]

But my code is:

```
scatterplot(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars)
```

and the output is like this
[image]

anybody knows how to change the formatting color like the picture 1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to specify the colors:

```
scatterplot(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars, col=c("green3", "red", "black"))
```

(These are the default colors; see `?scatterplot`.)

Comment: Did you actually try this code?  It does not work for me.

Comment: Odd. I just get green lines.

Comment: scatterplot(wt ~ mpg, data = mtcars,col=c("green3", "red", "black")) .

Comment: Hm, what happens if you change the colors, e.g., `col=c("blue", "red", "black")`(it works on my end)

Comment: apparently only the first color is recognized

Comment: Others, like @G5W, seem to have the same issue